# How to get exact Data types from parquet file writing to Csv file in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have  a  Parquet file  trying to convert into CSV File.

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Zip: decimal(18,2)(nullable = true)
```

## read parquet

df = spark.read.parquet("/temp/samplefile.parquet")

## write to CSV

df.write.csv("output/samplefile.csv")

After writing into csv  file  if I see the  Data Types  all are becoming  strings  only.

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string(nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Zip: string(nullable = true)
```

Can anyone suggest  me  how  can I get  the same  Datatypes  of  Parquet file  into Csv File.

Comment: when reading the csv (so that you can print the second schema with all fields as strings), did you use `.option("inferSchema", "true")`?

Comment: Actually i want  schema  in parquet file  should  be  write  to CSV  file. While  writing  I'm getting all columns  as  strings. For  example  Source Schema is  Integer and in target  also it should be integer not as  string

Comment: after you run `df.write.csv(...)` you call immediately `df.printSchema()` and then the column types are all strings? There are no other intermediate steps between `df.write...` and `df.printSchema()`?

Comment: @werner yes  all column types are coming  as strings .

Comment: strange.. no idea then